# how to get list of all files from folder inside java resources folder

Tags: java, io, wildfly-9

I am having **multiple files** inside **'protocol' folder**. I want to get list of files inside 'protocol' folder which is inside java resources folder (src/main/resources/protocol/...).

so when i tried to access any one file it works fine in eclipse IDE(using main method) and also in wildfly deployment. it gives lines inside files.

```
List<String> files = IOUtils.readLines(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("protocol/protocol1.csv"));
```

but when try to read folder it works fine in eclipse IDE(got list of file names) but does not work in  wildfly deployment it gives a blank list [].

```
List<String> files = IOUtils.readLines(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("protocol"));
```

i am using jboss wildfly server version:9.0.1 and java version "1.8.0_161".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sure. No such thing as "listing files in a folder" when your application is packed as e,g, an .ear file. So you might maintain your list of files e.g. in text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution to fetch all files inside folder.

if we try to access folder by getResource() method it will return in terms of vfs protocol and we need to convert that to

```
public List<String> loadFiles() throws IOException, Exception {
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/protocol");
        VirtualJarInputStream jarInputStream = (VirtualJarInputStream) resourceUrl.openStream();
        JarEntry jarEntry = null;
        while ((next = jarInputStream.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
            fileNames.add(jarEntry.getName());
        }
        return fileNames;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
URL url = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("protocol");
Path dirPath = Paths.get(url.toURI());
Stream<Path> paths = Files.list(dirPath);
List<String> names = paths
        .map(p -> p.getFileName().toString())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It shows that Path is a more refined generalisation of File.
It uses the `jar:file:` protocol (*protocols* like http:).

Comment: thanks tried your solution , when tried to get list (Files.list(dirPath)) it throws error as 'java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "vfs" not installed' any idea ?           The URI that i am getting is like 'vfs:/content/project_Name.war/WEB-INF/classes/protocol/'

Comment: Alternatively read all bytes from the getResourceAsStream. Sometimes that forms a list of entries. Of course there might well be a file system view implemented in [vfs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/). I do not know.